# let vs var javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo esta duda respecto a let y var, dentro de estos dos ejemplos utilizando var el codigo arroja 3 pero utilizando let el codigo arroja 2, por que es asi ?

```js
var printNumTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if(i === 2){
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
// returns 3
```

```js
'use strict';
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
// returns 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VAR**

---

En el primer caso donde la variable tiene definido `var` el valor de `i` es de alcance de función, es decir vive y existe tanto dentro de los paréntesis del `for` como dentro del `if` por lo cual puede completar el recorrido completo, es decir hacer estas iteraciones

```
Variable valor
   i       0
   i       1
   i       2
   i       3
```

Por consola nos devuelve esto

```
"La letra i vale: 0"
"La letra i vale: 1"
"La letra i vale: 2"
"otro valor3"
```

Fijate como a pesar de que yo puse un texto diferente dentro del `if` la continuidad del valor de `i` dentro de las iteraciones del `for` sigue por que `i` tiene un alcance mayor que let por lo cual su valor por cada vuelta no se pierde

**LET**

---

Sin embargo cuando la variable es de tipo `let` su existencia o alcance se limita a existir dentro del bloque `for`, mira este ejemplo

```
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log("La letra i vale: "+i)
  if(i === 2){
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return "otro valor"+i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Fijate los resultados que me arroja en consola

```
"La letra i vale: 0"
"La letra i vale: 1"
"La letra i vale: 2"
"otro valor2"
```

Fijate como el valor de i, una vez que las iteraciones del ciclo `for` terminan adquiere el valor 2 dentro del condicional `if`, el cual por cierto si lo cambias por 0 o 1 dentro de `i === 2` es el valor que te va a mostrar